# Как в еклипсе установить автодополнение кода для JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, settings

Здравствуйте,в интернете толком ничего не нашел,по данному поводу.
Вот мои настройки: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Надо в поле "Auto activation triggers for JavaScript" вместо . ввести (,.ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

И можно "Auto activation delay" поставить 0